# Issue with mapstraction-rails JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, mapstraction

I am using mapstraction-rails plugin and it worked fine in the rails 2.3 version.
When I upgraded the rails version to 3.2 I have started getting this error and map does not load

```
TypeError: this.location.toProprietary is not a function        

options.position = this.location.toProprietary(this.api);
```

In the firebug I see the error in the file: mxn.googlev3.core.js at line 484.

JQuery version is same as used in rails 2.3 i.e 1.4

I am using

```
@map.initialize_map(:onload=>false) #=> in rails 2.3

<%= @map.initialize_map(:onload=>false).first.html_safe %> #=> in rails 3.2 as this method returns the array with one element me in it.
```

method in the script tag to call the function which shows the map.

I have inspected the **this** element of **the this.location.toProprietary(this.api);** in the firebug and it seems the "this" element is different in rails 3.2. Please the screen shots.

In rails 2.3

[image]

In rails 3.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a file in the plug-in lib/mapstraction/latlon.rb.

It has a method:

```
def to_html
  html =[]
  html << "new mxn.LatLonPoint(#{@latitude},#{@longitude})"
  return html
end
```

I modified the return value and "**this**" object in the JavaScript was same as it was in the rails 2.3 version.

Modified method:

```
def to_html
  html =[]
  html << "new mxn.LatLonPoint(#{@latitude},#{@longitude})"
  return html.join(" ").html_safe
end
```